# Trying to get more attributes using AWS Cognito's UserInfo endpoint, can't seem to make the UserInfo Claims param work

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, openid, openid-connect

I'm using an AWS Cognito User Pool connected to our client's Azure AD Identity Provider. I was able to get some user information calling the UserInfo endpoint, but I couldn't get more attributes. I thought just mapping them in Cognito would be enough, but it wasn't. Apparently I have to specify which UserInfo Claims I want in the request, using a "claims" parameter? I tried doing something like this:

```
await axios({
    method: 'post',
    baseURL: Env.AWS_COGNITO_BASE_URL,
    url: '/oauth2/token',
    data: qs.stringify({
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: Env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      redirect_uri: this.redirectURI,
      code,
      claims: ['name', 'gender']
    }),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  })
```

following [these standard claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims). It didn't return the attributes I wanted, though.

I've also tried it in this format, but it didnt work either:

```
claims: {
            userinfo: {
              name: {essential: true},
              nickname: {essential: true},
              gender: {essential: true},
              address: {essential: true},
            },
         },
```

How should I do it then? I've seen the SAML returned using SAML-tracer and it contained those attributes.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The earlier answer is correct, but I'll expand it since this took me forever to understand. You need to ask for only `scope=openid` in the `/oath2/authorize?` scope and not more.

Here's how it might be set up now-

If you set up a request like this:

`https://{{user_pool_domain}}/oauth2/authorize?scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid&client_id={{client_id}}&redirect_uri={{user_pool_domain}}`

And then call the `/oath2/userInfo/`endpoint using that authorized requests' Access Token, you will not be able to return all attributes.

However, if you specify only the `scope=openid` in your authorization call, then use that Access Token in the `/oath2/userInfo/` GET request, that access token has permissions to read all attributes. So your initial call should look like this:

`https://{{user_pool_domain}}/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&client_id={{client_id}}&redirect_uri={{user_pool_domain}}`

Answer (score 0):

pass in what scopes you want when you call your authorize endpoint:

`https://{{user_pool_domain}}/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid`